# Problem with not functioning skip-chars-forward

Tags: forward-search

Context: *Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon, Emacs 27.1 lucid installed from repository, self compiled 28.4 gtk and 29.0.60 lucid.*

How to reproduce the problem?

1. Start Emacs with `emacs -Q`
2. Change the current buffer to `*scratch*`
3. Execute in the first line with point within a word:

**M-x eval-expression > Eval: (skip-chars-forward  "^ " 73)**

*the point will move to the next space*

4. Do the same in the second line of `*scratch*` and see that the point will stay at its position.

Can anyone here confirm this bug/problem which in my tests seems to occur in Emacs versions 27, 28 and 29?

Strange is that:
M-x eval-expression > Eval: (skip-chars-backward "^ " 73) *works sometimes for the same buffer and point position where forward doesn't (also the other way around may sometimes be the case).*

In other words, the behavior is not always 100% reproducible.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the text in your tested buffer?

Comment: @Shynur Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Drew : see my own answer to my question for the actual reason of my confusion which resulted from assuming that something does not work as expected and asking then the question. It is counter-intuitive for me to start skipping characters relative to a point position, but limit it in terms of absolute buffer values. If things work as intuitively expected there is no need to consult the documentation. If they don't ... it needs (or better say wastes?)  time and effort not only to provide the necessary explanations, but also for reading them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what `C-h f skip-chars-forward` says first:

> stopping before a char not in *STRING*, or at pos *LIM*.

I guess that it *may be* a documentation bug *to you*: what `skip-chars-forward` actually does may be:

> stopping before a char not in *STRING*; if *LIM* is provided, won't move beyond *LIM*.

If so, surely `skip-chars-forward("^ " 73)` won't move the cursor when your point is at [image].

---

Try `goto-char(73)`: [image]

See, the whole word `create` is beyond position 73, so the point won't move.

Comment: If you think my answer does solve your problem, it is likely that this function's *doc-string* is not clear enough for you.  You can send Emacs developers a Documentation Enhancement Request.

Comment: It's amazing to read how you by all possible means try to avoid naming the things by names they have really earned to be named with. In my eyes there are so many issues in code/documentation that the message to the Emacs *developers* (aren't *we* now part of the team with all the contributions here???)  comes down to *"best rewrite it all from scratch using consistent and up-to-date valid common sense terms and fundamentally different structure of code"*. Let's start a NeoMacs project. The excellent core ideas behind Emacs are maybe worth the effort.

Comment: @Claudio: Rewriting Emacs from scratch is very hard work (, I just guess it because I've never written a large software project).  As a kind of compromise, you can help improve the existing documentation of Emacs, so that if some latecomers/organization decide to rewrite Emacs someday in the future, they will benefit from your work.

Comment: I do my best communicating my newbie issues here providing answers to most of my questions myself. You know yourself that it's hard work. I don't think that going the established paths of improving Emacs is a good idea, because you are forced into giving in into the established ways first ... and if you really do ... you will start to see yourself that all is OK as it is. There are  http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_basics.html and http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/ there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

The issue/problem confusing you is your expectation that limiting of the distance while skipping chars relative to current point position has to be specified in terms of buffer absolute and not point relative position values.

Though both functions

```
(skip-chars-backward STRING &optional LIM)
(skip-chars-forward  STRING &optional LIM)
```

start from the current cursor/point which can be somewhere in the middle of the buffer, the value of the `LIM` parameter is interpreted as an absolute value of a position in buffer and not as a LIMit for the distance the point might travel while skipping chars.

The forward version of skipping characters needs a LIM value larger than the value of the point position in the buffer and the backward version a smaller one in order to make the point moving.

In other words in your special case the `forward` version skips chars only up to the absolute buffer character position of 73 and the `backward` version only for point positions larger than 73.

In order to achieve the functionality you have expected to obtain you need to turn the value for a maximal allowed distance of searching around the point to an absolute position value in the buffer using the current point position as follows :

```
 (skip-chars-forward   chars  (+  curr-point-pos  max-distance-from-point))
 (skip-chars-backward  chars  (-  curr-point-pos  max-distance-from-point))
```